# Unexpected "invalid character" error in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g, ora-00911

The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_NAME_HERE
```

causes `ORA-00911: invalid character` error. I tried to execute it using SQL Developer, Oracle SQL Developer, Toad, and from a java application.

`VIEW_NAME_HERE` is a view. The SQL query used to create the view follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1_alias.id2 AS col1 ,
                table1_alias.col2,
                table1_alias.col3
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table1 table1_alias
   ON table1.id1 =table1_alias.id2
WHERE  table1_alias.id2<>-55   AND table1_alias.LVL=1
UNION
SELECT col1 ,col2,col3
FROM table2 WHERE col1> 0 AND col4 = 1
AND LVL = 2
```

`SELECT *` from other views and tables works normally.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Can you post view definition?

Comment: What is the *actual* view name? Is the name enclosed in double-quotes in the `create view` command?

Comment: The query looks OK to me... I'd suggest recreating the view and make sure there is no compilation errors. Oracle issues a warning, but creates a view even if it has some errors

Comment: Yes, but Oracle doesn't throw ORA-00911; it throws `ORA-04063: view [schema].[viewname] has errors`

Comment: You haven't aliased `table`` but use the alias is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your test case on Oracle 10g:

```
SQL> create table table1 (id2 number, col2 number, col3 number, id1 number, lvl number);

Table created.

SQL> create table table2 (col1 number, col2 number, col3 number, col4 number, lvl number);

Table created.

SQL> create view view_name_here as
  2  SELECT DISTINCT table1_alias.id2 AS col1 ,
  3                  table1_alias.col2,
  4                  table1_alias.col3
  5  FROM table1
  6  INNER JOIN table1 table1_alias
  7     ON table1.id1 =table1_alias.id2
  8  WHERE  table1_alias.id2<>-55   AND table1_alias.LVL=1
  9  UNION
 10  SELECT col1 ,col2,col3
 11  FROM table2 WHERE col1> 0 AND col4 = 1
 12  AND LVL = 2;

View created.

SQL> select * from view_name_here;

no rows selected
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your view name contains an invalid character, but that when it was created the name was enclosed in double-quotes (a 'quoted identifier' according to the docs) so it was allowed; and when querying you're omitting the double-quotes. Something like:

```
create view "MY~VIEW" as select * from dual;

View created.

select * from MY~VIEW;
                *
Error at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

But this works:

```
select * from "MY~VIEW";

D
-
X
```

The actual character could be something else, of course, but the error (at least in SQL*Plus) helpfully highlights it with the `*`. The SQL reference has a [section on naming objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm); I'm guessing you're breaking rule 7.

Enclosing object names in double quotes is not considered good practice (though I'm sure opinions vary), usually because it causes problems with case differences, but can have other subtle effects like this. It's much easier to leaves the quotes off, let Oracle create all your objects with upper-case names, and spot any problems at object creation time.

Comment: the actual view name is `VIEW_PIP_EXEC_MINISTRY`.

Comment: OK, doesn't appear to be relevant then. You're doing exactly `select * from VIEW_PIP_EXEC_MINISTRY`? And none of the columns names (particularly the aliased one) have any odd characters or qoutes?